# Overriding ToString() in JValue and Json class

Tags: c#, json, tostring

The part of my assignment I am stuck on is as follows:

> Override the ToString method for the JValue and JsonValue classes in the JSON >Example [here](https://github.com/tosutton/CS-421/blob/master/Homework.md).
>   The output should be formatted nicely so it's easy to read.

I can override the JValue ToString Method with this code.

```
public override string ToString() {
    return Type.ToString() + ": " + Value.ToString();          
}
```

This successfully returns the Type property as a string. However, the Value property is returned as "Json.JsonObject". (The provided code is linked at the top by the way).

My instructor told us this could be completed with two overrides so I would assume the 2nd one would go in the JsonValue base class. I can't figure out how to access the values in the derived classes though.

I could individually override each derived classes ToString Method but that goes over my 2 override limit and still doesn't seem to work for Lists and Dictionaries.

Hopefully this isn't too vague but if it is, I basically just need help writing the two override methods so that if I were to run this code:

```
var json = new JValue { Object = new Dictionary<string, JValue>() };
json["name"] = new JValue("Joe Smith");
json["age"] = new JValue(31); 
if (json.Type == JType.Object)
{
        foreach (var value in json.Object)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(json.ToString())
        }
}
```

It  would return each JType and key value in the dictionary one by one.

As of now I am getting output like "Object: Json.JsonObject.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the following derived classes: JsonBool, JsonNumber, JsonString,

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

Also, in main you want:

```
foreach (var value in json.Object)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

You want each of the values not the object as a whole.